# Codeigniter select 2 users and send them emails

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

When I send email using the following code, it works fine.

```
public function select() {
$this->load->library('email', array('mailtype' => 'html'));
                $this->email->from('test@test.com','abc');
                $this->email->to('test1@test.com');
                $this->email->subject('test subject');
                $message = "Hello";
                $this->email->message($message);
                if($this->email->send()) {
                    $data["msg"] = "Email has been successfully sent.";
                    $this->load->view("view_test", $data);
                }
                else {
                    $data["msg"] = "Email sending failed.";
                    $this->load->view("view_test", $data);
                }
}
```

But when I want to select 2 users by id and then send them emails it does not work. Could you please check my code below and help me to find my mistake.

**Model**

```
public function did_select() {
        $this->db->select('email, name');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('user_id', 5);
        $this->db->where('user_id', 11);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function select() {
      if ($this->model_admin->did_select()) {
          foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)          {
              $name = $row['name'];
              $email = $row['email'];
                $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype' => 'html'));
                $this->email->from('test@test.com','abc');
                $this->email->to($email);
                $this->email->subject($name.'test subject');
                $message = "Hello";
                $this->email->message($message);

                if($this->email->send()) {
                    $data["msg"] = "Email has been sucessfully sent.";
                    $this->load->view("view_test", $data);
                }
                else {
                    $data["msg"] = "Email sending failed.";
                    $this->load->view("view_test", $data);
                }
              }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this two lines

```
    $this->db->where('user_id', 5);
    $this->db->where('user_id', 11);
```

This produces query like

```
Where user_id=5 and user_id=11
```

which is not you want. So you should replace the second line with

```
    $this->db->or_where('user_id', 11);
```

Also maybe your should remove view loading outside the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You already have returned `result_array` in model, so no need to double it. In controller try next:

```
if ($this->model_admin->did_select())
{
    $mails = $this->model_admin->did_select();
    foreach ($mails as $row)
    {
```